# Brackets Custom Key Binding for Right Arrow

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, brackets, touch-typing

I'd like to set up a custom key-binding for the right arrow key. I find that I have to break out from the 'home keys' and use the right arrow to move past quotations or parens that are auto-filled. I'm wondering if there's a convenient way to bind it to shift + space or something? I've looked at the json file, but not sure what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move past quotations, parentheses, curly braces just press the keys you use to create them **again** eg. shift + " after inserting a word in, do it again, shift + ". The cursor should move forward.
Shift + ( ..you insert something within, then pressing Shift + ) again should move the cursor out like it would when you press the right arrow.